# Overloading ">>" for a template?

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the ">>" operator so i can read and store a new Atlas<Animal *> from the keyboard.
The atlas template class has a list in which i'm storing pointers to each Animal object. Here is the code:

```
class Animal {
protected:
    std::string m_name;
public:
    Animal() {}
    Animal (std::string name): m_name {name} {}
    virtual void set_name(std::string name) {m_name = name;}
    virtual std::string get_name () {return m_name;}
    virtual std::string regn()  const { return "???"; }

    virtual ~Animal(){
    cout << "Destructor animal"<<'\n';}
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &in,  Animal* k){
    in>> k->m_name;

    return in;}
};   //pointers to objects from this class will be stored in Atlas2;

//declaration for >> operator

template <class T>
class Atlas2;
template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, const Atlas2<T>& A);

// Template class
template<class T>
class Atlas2{
public:
int nr_pesti;
   int  m_length;
    std::list<T> pages;
    Atlas2(){m_length = 0; nr_pesti = 0;}
    ~Atlas2(){}
    void adauga(T data);
   Atlas2 operator += (const T& data){
   this->m_length++;
   this->pages.push_back(data);
   return *this;}
    friend std::istream& operator>> <> (std::istream& in, const Atlas2<T>& A);
   };
template <class T>
istream operator>> (istream &in, const Atlas2<T> &A)
{
    in >> A.m_length;
    for (int i=1; i<=A.m_length; i++){
        T data = new T;
        cin >> data;
        A.pages.push_back(data);}
    return in;
}
template <class T>
void Atlas2<T>::adauga(T data){m_length = m_length+1;
pages.push_back(data);}

// here's the main:

int main(){
Atlas2<Animal *> Atlas3;
cin >> Atlas3;
return 0;}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I get this error when compiling:
`ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'Atlas2<Animal*>')` at line 58 (Where i type `cin>>Atlas3`) and these Warnings for the `>> operator` in the `template class` : `note: candidate: 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const Atlas2<T>&) [with T = Animal*; std::istream = std::basic_istream<char>]'`

Comment: At the very least `istream operator>> (istream &in, const Atlas2<T> &A)` should be `istream operator>> (istream &in, Atlas2<T> &A)` .

Comment: typo: The operator you declared as `friend` and the one you implemented have different signature, hence are two different overloads.

Comment: Why is `Atlas2` a template, if it's only going to store `Animal*`?

Comment: When you read `Atlas3`, the type `T` is `Animal*`, so you end up with `Animal* data = new Animal*;`, which is nonsense. (You need to devise a way to determine which type of animal to create *before* you create it.)

Comment: it stores pointers to objects from classes derived from animal base class, but for explicity i cut those off, and let only the part of the code with the problem. I sorted it out, the only problem was, as the first 2 comments said, my declaration was bad. Also, the `Animal * data = new Animal`  problem was sorted out, i saw that inconvenience, but the main problem was the bad declaration of operators. Currently i'm using a switch op with different insert methods for each type of animal in the `>> operator`. Thanks for the help and feedback